# Selenium cannot find the element under iframe

Tags: selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find the element under a iframe, and I've switch to the frame, but I still can not find the element
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVXna.png)

my HTML is in the link: http://pastebin.com/AShYrdxQ

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721263/cant-select-an-iframe-in-selenium-webdriver check it

Comment: code please which you tried to help on this?

Comment: are you sure you are inside the iframe

Comment: Yes, I can find the My World tab, but I can not click the CIC link

Answer (score 0):

Hi first of all **i found only one iframe on the page with id = msgframe** and also **please note that as per your source code that i frame is commented** so not playing any role hence please do not use switch to driver simply use

```
List<WebElement> commonElements = driver.findElements(By.className("Apps_Title"));
       for(int i =0;i<commonElements.size();i++){
           System.out.println(commonElements.get(i).getText());
       }
```

and it will work thanks hope this will help you.

Comment: it returns org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`driver.switchTo().frame("needle-frame-id-or-name");`

sometimes it's help me too:

`driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame("needle-frame-id-or-name");`

Comment: sometime iframe work with an other pages and need time to load them. Try any wait functions to be sure a page loaded.

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("frame"));