# Selenium can't find element (timeout exception) by xpath or ID with explicit wait

Tags: python, selenium, button, click

I'm trying to download a csv from [this](https://www.stats.govt.nz/experimental/covid-19-data-portal) website, by using selenium to click on the "download data" button from Python using this code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
URL = 'https://www.stats.govt.nz/experimental/covid-19-data-portal'
driver.get(URL)
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "download_data-show"))
    )
# Or this:
# element = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
#     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="download_data-show"]'))
#     )

element.click()
```

This is the html code I get when I inspect the button:

```
<button id="download_data-show" class="btn btn-modal action-button shiny-bound-input" type="button"> Download data </button>
```

When I run the python code, I'm getting a TimeoutException and when I try with an implicit wait of 30 seconds, I get the following error:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Download data"}
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.135)
```

Any ideas as to why the element can't be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download it from this URL (it's the iframe) https://statisticsnz.shinyapps.io/covid_19_dashboard/
I tested it with your code and it finds the selector.

If you want to use the original links regardless, maybe this will help you:
[Can't select an Iframe in selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721263/cant-select-an-iframe-in-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is, that your button is located in an iframe:
[image]

here is an answer how to get into the iframe:
[Select iframe using Python + Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534622/select-iframe-using-python-selenium)